# Performing selection on Attribute and Location of two different feature classes using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I have a point FC and a Polygon FC. Both FC have the attribute VILLAGE.
The point with Village = 1500 should be completely within the Polygon with Village = 1500.

How can I make a selection not only based on the location, but also on the attribute? In the End I want to see all Points/Polygons where the VILLAGE does not correspond.

Comment: Intersect the layers. Spatial Join would work then you only need to select where VILLAGE <> VILLAGE_1. This will give you the locations.. are you after the specific points? if so use geodatabase feature class (static OID) then both OID (point and polygon) are in the attribute table, join by attributes to the points/polygons you want to select and select by attributes where the joined VILLAGE attributes do not match.

Comment: Michael Miles-Stimson, put your comment in an answer so it be marked solved.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I just realised that you may not have seen the two previous comments.  If you want to add an answer I'll be happy to then delete mine that just quotes your comment to get this off the unclosed list.

Comment: All good @PolyGeo. I'll vote for yours instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> Intersect the layers. Spatial Join would work then you only need to
>   select where VILLAGE <> VILLAGE_1. This will give you the locations..
>   are you after the specific points? if so use geodatabase feature class
>   (static OID) then both OID (point and polygon) are in the attribute
>   table, join by attributes to the points/polygons you want to select
>   and select by attributes where the joined VILLAGE attributes do not
>   match.